# Не выводится результат поиска директорий по маске

Tags: c#, winforms, search, click

В Windows Forms по клику на кнопке нужно вывести в TextBox список файлов, которые соответствуют шаблону поиска в указанном каталоге.
После клика ничего не меняется.

````
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string SearchDirectory = tbSearchDirectory.Text;
            string NameMask = tbNameMask.Text;
            string[] dirs = Directory.GetFiles(SearchDirectory, NameMask, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            foreach (string dir in dirs)
            {
                tbFoundFiles.Text = dir;   
            }

        }

    } ```
````

Comment: Наверное правильно было-бы указать маску в примере, ту которая в текст боксе, ту по которой получится холодильник с бородой и хвостом.

Comment: @DigitalCore не совсем понял. Ввожу набор символов, например "1", "mp4", слова из названий файлов и вложенных директорий (""Cheetah", "Video", "Course")

Answer (score 0):

Получилось вывести один файл

```
public async void BtnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btnSearch = (Button)sender;
    btnSearch.Enabled = false;        

    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(tbSearchDirectory.Text, tbNameMask.Text, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                tbFileOnCheck.Text = file;
            }));
        }    
    });
    btnSearch.Enabled = true;      
}
```